# Rewriting $\max \log \det (I+ X + Y + Y^T)$ as max-det problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory

The following optimization is convex:
\begin{align}
\max_{X\succ0,Y} &\ \ \log \det (I + X +Y + Y^T)\\
& \text{s.t.} \begin{pmatrix} X& Y \\ Y^T & Z \end{pmatrix}\succeq 0, \ \ \ \mathbf{Tr}(X)\le P
\end{align}
where $Z\succ0$ and $P>0$ are given.

My question is whether the decision variable $Y$ can be transformed or replaced with a be positive semi-definite decision variable. My motivation is to write the optimization as a standard max-det problem or in a nicer form in order to show that the maximizer is unique.

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear from my formulation, but $Y$ is not necessarily positive

Comment: I see. If $I+X+Y+Y^T$ is not positive definite over the entire feasible region, the objective is not strictly concave (and not defined everywhere).

Comment: I can show/assume that it is positive definite in the domain, but is it sufficient for a unique maximizer? My idea was to convert it first to a standard max-det problem by changing  the variable $Y$ to an LMI or linear equality.

Comment: The log-det function is strictly concave on the set of positive definite matrices, but $f(X,Y) = I+X+Y+Y^T$ is not, as it is constant along the ray $X+Y+Y^T=0$ (nevertheless the objective is concave and the maximal value is unique).